# Full Text Search Sqlite query at column's starting character

Tags: java, android, sqlite, full-text-search

I have a problem about create a query for text-searching starting at begining of column character. For example: I have a table 'BOOK' with a column 'TITLE'. I have 3 rows in 'BOOK' table with 'TITLE' values are: 'ANDROID APPLICATION', 'ANDROID APP DEVELOPMENT' and 'ANDROID APPLICATION PROGRAMMING'.

Now when my input is 'ANDROID APP', I need all 3 rows matched. When I type 'ANDROID APPLICATION', I need 2 rows matched: 'ANDROID APPLICATION' and 'ANDROID APPLICATION PROGRAMMING'. And when I type 'APP' or 'APPLICATION', I need no row matched (because we want to start searching at begining character of column value).

I've read the SQLite FTS document but I dont know how to use prefix query, phrase query... together with AND, OR, NOT operation to solve my problem? Anyone could give me an approriate query syntax?

Comment: Why are you using a *full* text search table when you search only from the beginning?

Comment: Because my app needs that feature :)
Now I have an idea. I create a query with an addition offsets column in the result and check the third integer (indicate the matched position as SQLite FTS documentation mentioned) in offsets string. If that integer equals zero that means the string match at the beginning. But I failed to create a query because of no offsets column in the result ? Could you please give me an example query ?

Answer (score 1):

FTS cannot search from the beginning of a column value.
(Actually, it can, but this is undocumented and not enabled in Android.)

To search from the beginning, you have to use `LIKE 'pattern%'`.
If you want this to be efficient, you have to use this with a normal table and a case-insensitive index ([COLLATE NOCASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
String name = your book name which entered by search box;

String sql ="select "+TITLE+" from "+BOOK+" where TITLE like '"+ name +"%'";
```

Comment: FTS said that the text-search query use MATCH instead of LIKE. And as your sql string, I think when I type 'APPLICATION' in search box, 2 rows would matched the query:'ANDROID APPLICATION PROGRAMMING' and 'ANDROID APPLICATION. But I need no row matched because I want to check from the starting word of column value.

Comment: yeah right, now check my edited answer..it will search as per your needed.

Comment: As I mentioned above, Full Text Search use MATCH instead of LIKE because the searching time using LIKE is too long. Unfortunately, FTS using MATCH does not support syntax '%' Any other ideas?